# ActivePerl ppm error "database disk image is malformed"

Tags: perl, activeperl

After an unexpected interrupt any ppm command gives me this error:

C:>ppm
ppm gui failed: DBD::SQLite::db selectrow_array failed: database disk image is malformed

How can I fix ppm?

Comment: My 1st step would be to ask on ActiveState's PPM forum...

Answer (score 1):

Open:

```
C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\ActiveState\ActivePerl
```

Delete everything.

Run `ppm` again and it'll rebuild.